# Python module import error

Tags: python

i am struggling with a strange error (may be it should not be strange for experts) with my python code.

When i write down a python script and save it to Desktop( to reduce the system drive load i have changed my Desktop folder destination to "G:" drive on my System) and when i run this script from the desktop it  does not import the module with import statement (for example "import math") rather error comes out "module not found (something like that)"  where as when i save the same script in "C:" drive it will run properly without any occurrence of error.

Now i am looking for any method or any statement which could simply be added to the script and  able to run my code from anywhere in the system without error.

Comment: What did you try? Where does it fail? What errors do you get?

Comment: I have changed my Question Please review it so that my account could activate with full functionality. Presently i am not able to share my doubts  thanks :(

Comment: If you have a different question, you should post a different question.

Comment: @usethedeathstar i am not able to post any Question some features of my account has been blocked due to negative voting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("> >.+<br")
print pattern.findall(string)
#  --------------------------------text----------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1732138

Comment: I have changed my Question Please review it so that my account could activate with full functionality. Presently i am not able to share my doubts  thanks :(